# georeference in QGIS using Open Layers

Tags: georeferencing

I'm using QGIS to do georeference scan of the map. I have to do it in UTM zone 36N. The problem is I want to do it by creating control points and use  background maps available in Open Map Layers (Bings Aerial, Google Map etc.). They are in PseudoMercator- not possible to change coordinates. What is the best way to resolve this problem? I've already received adjacent area shp and georeferenced TIFFs so it's just continuation of the work. There is no exceptions, it has to be in 36 N.

Comment: While web Mercator is an awful projection for doing any GIS work of value, you certainly *don't* have "no exceptions". In fact, you have an infinite number of options (that being the number of coordinate systems available at any place on the globe), all of which ending in reprojecting to your target projection.

Comment: If you use QuickMapServicev plug-in instead of OpenLayers plug-in on the fly re-projection is available for tile services, too. This way no need for georeferencing in UTM zone 36N, but probably it slows down the system.